# How Do I Use A Terraform Data Source To Reference A Managed Prefix List?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to update a terraform module to add a new security group, which will have an inbound rule populated with two managed prefix lists. The prefix lists are shared to my AWS account from a different account using AWS Resource Access Manager, however I have tried referencing prefix lists created within my own AWS account and am seeing the same error.

Below is the terraform I am using:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "akamai_sg" {
  name                   = "akamai-pl-sg"
  description            = "Manage access from Akamai to ${var.environment} alb"
  vpc_id                 = var.vpc_id
  tags                   = merge(var.common_tags, tomap({ "Name" = "akamai-pl-sg" }))
  revoke_rules_on_delete = true
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "akamai_to_internal_alb" {
  for_each = toset(var.domains_inc_akamai)

  type                     = "ingress"
  description              = "Allow Akamai into ${var.environment}${var.domain_name_suffix}-alb"
  from_port                = var.alb_listener_port
  to_port                  = var.alb_listener_port
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.akamai_sg.id
  prefix_list_ids          = [data.aws_prefix_list.akamai-site-shield.id, data.aws_prefix_list.akamai-staging.id]
}

data "aws_prefix_list" "akamai-site-shield" {
  filter {
    name   = "prefix-list-id"
    values = ["pl-xxxxxxxxxx"]
  }
}

data "aws_prefix_list" "akamai-staging" {
  filter {
    name   = "prefix-list-id"
    values = ["pl-xxxxxxxxxx"]
  }
}
```

The terraform error I am revieving reads:
*"Error: no matching prefix list found; the prefix list ID or name may be invalid or not exist in the current region"*

Is anyone able to help, or see where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the error tells you everything you need to know, i.e., it's trying to tell you where to look for issues.

Comment: Yes however the prefix lists do exist in the same account and same region, hence I suspect there may be something wrong with the terraform.

Answer (score 4):

Would not be the following possible?

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.foo.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3"
}

data "aws_prefix_list" "s3" {
  prefix_list_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3.prefix_list_id
}
```

It seems the solution is to use:

```
data "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "example" {
  filter {
    name   = "prefix-list-name"
    values = ["my-prefix-list"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work. Where is the aws_prefix_list data source getting the prefix_list_id from within the aws_vpc_endpoint? This is just referencing a vpc endpoint with no associated prefix lists no?

Comment: Looks like it was a simple mistake. I should have been using the 'aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list' as opposed to just 'aws_prefix_list'. This has now worked, thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I also fell into the same trap.. The TF docs suggest using 'aws_prefix_list' when importing using data, but correct approach to reference a customer managed prefix list is to use 'aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `aws_prefix_list`, use `aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list`. According to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/5.32.1/docs/data-sources/prefix_list), that's the recommended method.

> aws_prefix_list provides details about a specific AWS prefix list (PL) in the current region.

> This can be used both to validate a prefix list given in a variable
> and to obtain the CIDR blocks (IP address ranges) for the associated
> AWS service. The latter may be useful e.g., for adding network ACL
> rules.

> The aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list data source is normally more
> appropriate to use given it can return customer-managed prefix list
> info, as well as additional attributes.